# Modified database layer to use Amazon RDS's read replicas and master in MySQL

Tags: database, mysql

I've been searching without success a plugin that might split Joomla's read queries to one endpoint and write queries to another endpoint. This would enable us to use Amazon RDS's read replicas (MySQL).

Does anybody know how to achieve this, or if there is some plugin/extension available?

UPDATE: I tried to do my own driver based on what was suggested in one of the answers, I did not suceed to make it work. I created a gist so anybody can easily help me solve the issue: https://gist.github.com/siran/77d65f9375cf7b787c83/revisions

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To play with MySQL configutation, the solution is beyond a system plugin. It has to catch every query and manage the applied configuration.

In my opinion, the best solution would be to create a new database driver (or modify one of the core drivers). For example, you can create a **mysqliaws.php** and modify the required files to add it into the core.

On the other hand, Amazon could have its own PHP driver to route queries to the right instance.

Comment: I agree Amazon should take care of routing the queries, but it doesn't. So I'll try your answer, good idea. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to emulate mysqli drivers, but it's cumbersome and I didn't make it :( ... do you know if someone has done something similar?

Comment: I created a gist with the modified driver: https://gist.github.com/siran/77d65f9375cf7b787c83/revisions

Comment: The idea is Ok. As a first proof of concept, I would just modify JDatabaseMySQLi to test the modifications scope. Once you get the final version, you can go for the extra step of Joomla "new driver" development. For example, you could just create JDatabaseMySQLiAws extending JDatabaseMySQLi (most methods are public/protected).

Comment: Yes I basically did that, the only difference being I created a new file and put this is configuration.com I get the error posted on the Gist,

    Duplicate entry 'h2rgkf6idru0r2lnpv5iqib3i1' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) VALUES ('h2rgkf6idru0r2lnpv5iqib3i1', 0, '1428946167')